# How to search only curly braces i.e. { } in Solr search using Solr URL

Tags: solr, content-search

As shown in the picture, I have some tokens in a computed field and want to search all those fields which have `{ }`, but not able to do so, although I have put escape sequence i.e.

[image]

I have tried to execute the same from Sitecore and have not been able to find any records as well. After looking into Solr query find that it removes `{` from search text, as shown below

[image]

So should we assume that we can't search `{}` in Solr or there is any workaround for it?

[image]

Comment: Search query seems correct, are you getting results with an exact match. like apiurl_t:"exact string"

Comment: yes. for apiurl_t: *yyy*, getting string MF/v2/productdetail/BreakpointPricingHistory/67065R812/{yyyy-mm-dd}

Comment: can you try this apiurl_t: " * \{ * "     .Comments don't allow me to put a star (*). so I've used space after star. but basically try query without spaces before and after *

Comment: i have already tried it, you can see that in screenshot in question

Comment: yep, just put double quotes as well before after Asterisk.

Comment: i had tried that too, here is the result: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"apiurl_t: \"\\{\"",
      "_":"1646312735346"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your screenshot, your field type is `text_general` that uses `StandardTokenizerFactory` *(like this)*:

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

**Indexing**: your `{ }` characters are ignored by `StandardTokenizerFactory` on indexing level and are used to tokenize your text.

I don't see a reason to use `text_general` for URLs, why you don't use `string`?

If you really need `text_general` for your field: best option is to create your own field type with your specific tokenizer behavior *(instead of changing `text_general` schema)*. You can use `WhiteSpaceTokenizer`, `PatternTokenizerFactory`, `KeywordTokenizerFactory` depends on your needs instead of `StandardTokenizerFactory`.

**Quering**:
your workaround by using `\` for escaping should work for quering. But your `text_general` field type uses the same `StandardTokenizerFactory` for querying, so your `{ }` are also escaped from your query.

So, best solution is to change your field type to `string`. If you cant do it by some reasons - implement your own field type with needed tokenizers on indexing and querying levels.

*P.S. I am not 100% sure for querying with `{`, as far as I remember it was a bug in old Sitecore versions with Lucene search that Sitecore force calls Lucene QueryParser.Escape on query time, but I hope it was fixed a long time ago and it works fine with querying without StandardTokenizerFactory.*

Comment: Thanks @x3mxray, i am able to search using { now in Solr url, although not able to search { in CMS, as i guess there we can't give field name to search from.